# Jquery Tooltip Plugin used to display on mozilla addon panel. Will it effect my review process by AMO reviewers?

Tags: firefox, jquery-plugins, firefox-addon, mozilla, jquery-tooltip

I am using a jquery tooltip plugin to display the tooltip text in my addon panel. The jquery tooltip that am using in my addon is Lightweight jQuery Tooltip Plugin - TipTip

My question is , Will this affect my addon review process by AMO reviwers?

Comment: If its within a contentScript in the panel then its ok.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any known JavaScript library. Although it will produce a warning during the validation process like this one:

```
JS Library Detected
Warning:
JavaScript libraries are discouraged for simple add-ons, but are generally accepted.
```

Also, your JS library must submitted as it is, no modification on the libraries code. As far as I know, AMO checks the checksums of the known libraries files to see if they are identical.

Check out this question in Developer FAQ: 
[Can I use a JavaScript library like jQuery, MooTools or Prototype to build my add-on?](https://addons.mozilla.org/developer_faq)